# Hybrid app with remote html and local cordova.js

Tags: android, cordova

I have a website that I want to enhance on mobiles with a hybrid app.  Ideally the app would load the remote site over http but load the platform specific code locally.  I've tried to set up a Cordova project to do this but am having lots of trouble.  Cordova 4.3.1, Cordova Android 3.7.2 on a Nexus 7 Android 4.4.4 has been my environment.  (The google maps plugin is for Cordova Android < 4.)

If I try to load file:///android_assets/www/cordova.js from an http site, chromium says `Not allowed to load local resource`.  I tried to set up a local URL scheme but don't know what android-specific code to put where.

Is this the right way to make a hybrid app?  Is there a cordova plugin to allow loading file: from http:?

---

I also tried using an iframe and passing messages to indicate cordova is enabled and which plugins are installed, but I don't want to deal with having the http server re-serve the same js files that are already available locally.

I also thought to download the website and access it over file: but I imagine I will have the same problem trying to access http resources.

Comment: How did you solve it eventually?

Comment: @user2335065 http://stackoverflow.com/a/31019431/192798 i gave up and put the `file:` resources on `http:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to make a hybrid app, but I got it working by serving assets over http with https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd .

On the local page bundled with the app I have added:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            var httpd = cordova.plugins.CorHttpd;
            httpd.startServer({
                'www_root': '',
                'port': 8080,
                'localhost_only': false
            }, function (url) {
                // if server is up, it will return the url of http://<server ip>:port/
                // the ip is the active network connection
                // if no wifi or no cell, "127.0.0.1" will be returned.
                document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = "server is started: <a href='" + url + "' target='_blank'>" + url + "</a>";
                location.replace('http://192.168.0.134:9090/homechooser/beta/#' + JSON.stringify({'cordova.js': url + '/cordova.js'}));
            }, function (error) {
                document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = 'failed to start server: ' + error;
            });
        }, false);
    </script>
    <div id="url"></div>
```

Then on the remote webpage I have added:

```
(function () {
    var hash;
    if (location && location.hash)
        try {
            hash = JSON.parse(location.hash.substring(1));
        } catch (e) {
        }
    if (hash && hash['cordova.js'])
        $.getScript(hash['cordova.js'], function () {
            alert("Running cordova.js");
        });
})();
```

now to see if cordova can actually be used this way...

Comment: For anyone searching for this issue.. the below guide works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017

Answer (score 6):

I am able to load local `cordova.js` on remote html using cordova-plugin-file (`cdvfile://`) plugin .

1. Add cordova-plugin-file plugin to your cordova project
   https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/
2. Confirm cdvfile URI for `cordova.js` using below sample code(Android example)

```js
    checkCordovaJSPath('file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js');
    
    function checkCordovaJSPath(jsUri) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(jsUri, function success(fileEntry){
                console.log("got cordova.js file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
                console.log('cordova.js cdvfile URI: ' + fileEntry.toInternalURL());
               
    });
    }
```

3. Load `cordova.js` using `cdvfile://localhost` on remote html.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"/>
```

Comment: Some resources, such as: https://medium.com/@barsh/loading-cordova-js-from-a-website-27966844ba56, report that the cdvfile://... doesn't work on Android. But I confirm that it does, cf. the current answer. Probably step 2 is the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Thing is your are trying to load a web-url on the local hosted app, imagine doing the same thing on Native Android App, what would you do? you will place a web-client or a web-browser in your app. But Cordova/Phonegap already uses Web-Browser to render your pages. So its like a using web-browser inside a web browser.

You need to install **[InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)** which will give you the ability to load 3rd party hosted web pages.

**Sample Code**

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://yourWebPage.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }
```

Comment: but that won't allow `yourWebPage.com` to use `cordova.js`

Comment: oh but that gives me an idea to use `ref.executeScript(details, callback);` to load `cordova.js` in `yourWebPage.com`.  will try it and let you know.

Comment: offcourse thats intended. If you use google.com inplace of yourWebPage.com then why Google.com allow your js to run on his webpage ?

Comment: `executeScript` injects your script locally in your browser, not in the webpage.

Comment: i don't want to use `google.com`.  i want to use `yourWebPage.com` and i want it to access `cordova.js`.  i allow `cordova.js` to run on my web page because i trust it.  chromium is putting security in the other way.  it's not allowing access to `file:` because it doesn't trust `http:`.

Comment: yes, i want to inject `cordova.js` locally into the browser, but it seems to do it by injecting into the DOM, which doesn't help and gives the same issue: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js`

Comment: @Jayen I was giving just an example for using `google.com`, btw did you try with the `executeScript` ?

Comment: yes, but it does the same thing as adding `<script>` manually.  i'm looking at https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd now

Comment: For anyone searching answers for this recently... I followed the below guide and it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017

Answer (score -1):

The cdvfile solution will not work for active content (js files) because of the mixed content policy. Here is how to make it work:

For android: Disable mixed content policy by putting the following code inside the pluginInitialize method of your cordova plugin:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            final WebSettings settings = ((WebView)this.webView.getView()).getSettings();
      settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)

Then include local cordova.js using:

```
<script src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

For ios: I submitted a PR to the file plugin which solves the mixed content problem on ios: apache/cordova-plugin-file#296 The fixed version is available at: https://github.com/guylando/cordova-plugin-file If you load a remote site https://example.com on the webview then it allows to access local files using the url: https://example.com/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js instead of cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js And by this solves the mixed content problems

Include local cordova.js using:

```
<script src="/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: your solution is hard to follow, compared to pramoda's answer.  see the answering guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , particularly "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: can you elaborate on "your cordova plugin"?  i'm writing a cordova app, not a plugin.

Comment: My personal conclusion is that cordova does not always have a plugin for everything and the plugins environment is built by very few individuals which mostly didn't update their repositories for years. If you want to use latest android/ios features you have no choice but to add your own plugin and in that plugin you will be able to insert any ios and android code for all the features you want which aren't available in other plugins.

Comment: Also this has a big performance benefit because adding a new plugin for every small thing makes the app performance slower because every plugin requires its javascript file to be loaded on app start.

Comment: If you use ionic webview then they have a flag for that in version 3.0.0 https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/231

Comment: is there a cordova command to add your version of your plugin to my app?  if yes, can you please add that to your answer?

Comment: Replace the npm package name with the url of the github repository in the normal plugin addition command